# Should I use weak to let UICollectionViewCell hold an NSManagedObject, to avoid from interferencing with CoreData memory management?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Currently, I have the following core data backed collection view, which enable users to perform add/ delete/ modify/ reordering.

[image]

It will be much more convenient to achieve what I, if I let `UICollectionViewCell`, to hold its corresponding `NSManagedObject`. So that I can each perform add/ delete/ modify/ reordering.

I was wondering, should I mark the `NSManagedObject` as weak, to avoid from interferencing with how CoreData manage its memory?

---

### Using weak

```
class TabInfoSettingsCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    // NSManagedObject. Use weak, as we do not want to inteference with how CoreData manage its memory.
    private weak var nsTabInfo : NSTabInfo?
```

---

Or, such concern is invalid. We can simply use strong

### Use strong

```
class TabInfoSettingsCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    // NSManagedObject.
    private var nsTabInfo : NSTabInfo?
```

---

Or, such concern is valid and using weak is unsafe (as it can become nil in some edge case?). We can use a struct, which contains everything including objectID, but excluding `NSManagedObjectContext`.

### Use struct

```
class TabInfoSettingsCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    // struct. Contains everything including objectID, but excluding NSManagedObjectContext.
    private var tabInfo : TabInfo?
```

This come with the cost of having to create a struct out from `NSManagedObject` each time, in cellForItemAt.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
    tabInfoSettingsCell.update(nsTabInfo.toTabInfo())
    ...
}
```

---

May I know, which is the correct design, as far as safe memory management is concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a strong reference to your managed object. You are not creating a circular reference which would be a reason to use weak.

e.g this would be bad:

```
cell.tabInfo = managedObject
managedObject.cell = cell
```

Also a style point, namespacing your classes with NS leads to confusing your object with Apple classes and should be avoided.

Comment: Will it interference with core data memory management technique like faulting?

Comment: No. A NSManagedObject is self contained. It’s not aware of what is using it. If a property or relationship needs to be faulted the internal goo will do that. Treat it like a sealed box.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `NSFetchedResultsController` backed `UICollectionView`, all of objects lifecycle is driven by `NSFetchedResultsController` without you ever needing to worry about these cases.

Every time a change happens in your store, you are notified of that change and you can ask `NSFetchedResultsController` to provide you the latest data.

You don't need to worry too much about a cell holding a strong reference to the model. Cells are reused anyway and this reference will keep changing every time a cell is reused.

You can use strong references to your models in the cells and it won't create issues for you because the cells are refreshed with latest data by design.

Comment: Will it interference with core data memory management technique like faulting?

Comment: That's a completely different topic and `weak` / `strong` does not impact the faulting behaviors of `CoreData`.